# jQuery pushing an img element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get all table row data, push them into an array and get them back. But at the moment I can only get the values of first three columns but I can't get the src of image.

I tried `data.push($(this).val(), $('img').attr('src'));` but didn't work.

```
                      data = [];
                      $("#car-control-sum tbody>tr").remove();
                        $("#car-control-table tbody select, #car-control-table tbody input, #car-control-table tbody img").each(function(){
                            data.push($(this).val());
                        });

                        <table data-role="table" id="car-control-table" class="ui-responsive ui-shadow">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width:158px;border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;">Kontrollpunkt</th>
                            <th style="width:110px;border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;">OK</th>
                            <th style="width:158px;border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;">Kommentar</th>
                            <th style="width:110px;border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;">Ta bilde</th>
                            <th style="width:110px;border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;">Det.</th>

                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr class="car-row">
                            <td>
                                <select class="select-lys">
                                    <option value="Stotdempere">Stotdempere, fjaerer</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <select id="checkup_ok" data-role="slider" style="height:100px;">
                                    <option value=" ">Off</option>
                                    <option value="OK">On</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <input style="border: 2px solid #ccc;height:45px;" id="car-control-comment" name="car-control-comment"/>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <a style="height:40px;width:40px;margin-bottom:40px;"
                                   class="checkup_cam ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-b ui-corner-all ui-icon-camera"></a>
                                <img class="checkup_thumb" style="padding-top:10px;"
                                     src="http://www.mountainmansocialmedia.com/_site/wp-content/themes/juiced/img/thumbnail-default.jpg"
                                     height="40" width="40">
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <a style="height:40px;width:40px;" id="car-control-add"
                                   class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-b ui-corner-all ui-icon-plus"></a>
                            </td>
                            <td>

                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        </tbody>

                    </table>
```

**How can I push an image src into the data array?**

Answer (score 1):

Consider using .prop() instead of .attr()

```
var src = $('#image-id').prop('src');
data.push(src);
```

Comment: Regarding src attribute, there is nothing wrong with using `attr()` method AFAIK. BTW, `prop()` returns absolute path, not sure this is expected result here. **EDIT:** OP is setting src attribute with absolute path, so not an issue here

Answer (score 1):

Try substituting `this.value` for `$(this).val()`

```
   $("#car-control-table tbody select, #car-control-table tbody input, #car-control-table tbody img")
   .each(function() {
     data.push(this[this.nodeName === "input" ? "value" : "src"])
   });
```

```js
var data = [];
                      //$("#car-control-sum tbody>tr").remove();
                      $("#car-control-table tbody select, #car-control-table tbody input, #car-control-table tbody img").each(function() {
                        data.push(this.value || this.src);
                      });
console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table data-role="table" id="car-control-table" class="ui-responsive ui-shadow">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:158px;border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;">Kontrollpunkt</th>
      <th style="width:110px;border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;">OK</th>
      <th style="width:158px;border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;">Kommentar</th>
      <th style="width:110px;border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;">Ta bilde</th>
      <th style="width:110px;border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;">Det.</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="car-row">
      <td>
        <select class="select-lys">
          <option value="Stotdempere">Stotdempere, fjaerer</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <td>
        <select id="checkup_ok" data-role="slider" style="height:100px;">
          <option value=" ">Off</option>
          <option value="OK">On</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <td>
        <input style="border: 2px solid #ccc;height:45px;" id="car-control-comment" name="car-control-comment" />
      </td>

      <td>
        <a style="height:40px;width:40px;margin-bottom:40px;" class="checkup_cam ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-b ui-corner-all ui-icon-camera"></a>
        <img class="checkup_thumb" style="padding-top:10px;" src="http://www.mountainmansocialmedia.com/_site/wp-content/themes/juiced/img/thumbnail-default.jpg" height="40" width="40">
      </td>

      <td>
        <a style="height:40px;width:40px;" id="car-control-add" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-b ui-corner-all ui-icon-plus"></a>
      </td>
      <td>

      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: As a side note, `this.src` returns absolute path. And if `this.value` is empty string, `this.src` would be used. BTW, `this.value` couldn't be what is expected in case of `select multiple` would be used (not the case here but...). My bet would be to used: `data.push($(this).is('img') ? $(this).attr('src') : $(this).val());`  **EDIT:** OP is setting src attribute with absolute path, so not an issue here

Comment: @A.Wolff _"if this.value is empty string, this.src would be used. "_ Yes, absolute path would be returned . If `this.value` is empty string, `this.src` would not be returned , as `.each()` iterates one element per loop cycle ; if `this.value` property contains empty string, `""` should be returned

Comment: In case of empty string as value for input, the property `src` is used. You can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/7afmwdzL/2/

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes, you are correct ; see updated post , http://jsfiddle.net/7afmwdzL/5/

Comment: Thanks this worked for me  `data.push($(this).is('img') ? $(this).attr('src') : $(this).val());`